# Apache Cassandra IOPS due to BLOOM FILTER? 1 IOPS of 1 byte per every insert

Tags: c#, cassandra, bloom-filter

Can Bloom Filter cause physical IO to filter.DB per insert command?
We are currently performing a performance matchup and Cassandra is one of our options. We experience a very strange phenomenon in Cassandra. This question is not about performance though. 
We are using Cassandra 2.1.2 (apache community version) on Windows server 2012. only 2 nodes and no replication.
We use NAS storage.

Keyspace definition:
CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} 
Table definition:
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable (
    signature uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    data blob
)

CommitLog is stored on local machine. Data is stored on NAS. 
While performing a 100M rows insert (using C# driver) to the table we experience IO of a byte per row added to the filter.db. (We used MS process monitor in order to observe this phenomenon). 
This is causing many IOPS (about 4000-5000 per second) only for the filter.db file.
We expected to see zero (0) writes in NAS most of the time and lots of activity only due to MemTable flush to NAS and or compaction. instead we see tons of tiny IOPS every second. 
When we disabled bloom filters as follows:

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable (
    signature uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    data blob
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 1.0

We saw no IOPS per row inserted. Which is the expected phenomenon as far as we understand. . 
We do however also require Bloom Filter for reads at a later stage.
The question is, why do we get IO per row written in filter.db? and why isn't that a part of a MemTable flush?
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Windows is only experimentally supported now in C*
And NAS is never a good way to use C*

Comment: Although we totally agree that NAS is not the way to go, the question is not about performance, it is about actual IO taken place while performing inserts. 1 byte is written to the filter.db per 1 insert. This is not the expected behavior. So Windows for Cassandra is not supported for production environments? And still if that is the case. why do we see these IOPS. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: I assume you mean c# and not c* unless c* is short for Cassandra. This is a bit confusing. Are you saying that c# driver is not production ready or that Cassandra on windows is not production ready?

Comment: C* is cassandra. I would argue it is not production ready although there is a strong effort right now to make it work.

Comment: OK, we do encounter also row cache behavior on WIN that we do not encounter on Linux. teh .NET client is performing a select * and it fills the rowcache but when we perform same code again it does not get a cache hit!! When we try same thing via CQL all is working just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I mean when we perform it via CQLSH it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bloom filter issue. its sue to NAS. if we use Cassandra (We tested WIN version) on the local disk then the Bloom Filter writes are cached in OS level but if we use NAS then it is not cached and casues an actual IOps.

We still do not get key cache and row cache to work on Windows but I will open a seperate question on that.

Thank you for providing us information